Use GlobalVariables.dll from Python
I am using GlobalVariables within Multicharts with no issues. For example, if I create this indicator:
inputs:     DayValue(18);
AccuracySetNamedInt("Day", DayValue);
RecalcLastBarAfter(1);

I can get the value of the variable "Day" from other indicator with no issues:
value1 = AccuracyGetNamedInt("Day", -1);

I need to get the value of the "Day" variable from Python. I have tried this code:
import ctypes

# Load the GlobalVariable.dll
gv = ctypes.CDLL("C:\\Program Files\\MultiCharts\\GlobalVariable.dll")

# Define the function prototypes
gv.AccuracyGetNamedInt.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_int]
gv.AccuracyGetNamedInt.restype = ctypes.c_int

# Access the global variable
variable_name = "Day".encode('utf-8')
default_value = -1
value = gv.AccuracyGetNamedInt(variable_name, default_value)

print(f"The value of the global variable 'Day' is: {value}") 

However, I get and error that reads:
AttributeError: function 'AccuracyGetNamedInt' not found

If I get the list of functions of the DLL I get this (dir(gv):
['LoadLibrary',
 '__class__', '__class_getitem__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getstate__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_dlltype']

The function 'AccuracyGetNamedInt' is not available in the DLL. Should I try to get the value of the variable using other function of the DLL?

dir(gv) does not list functions available in the DLL. You need a tool like dumpbin in the Windows SDK.

Maybe ctypes.WinDLL instead of ctypes.CDLL?
